# In the multi-linear regression, how is the value of weight $b_2$ calculated?

Tags: machine-learning, learning-algorithms, linear-regression

In multivariate linear regression (linear regression with more than one variable) the model is $yi = b_0 + b_1x_{1i} + b_2x_{2i} + ...$ , and so on. But how is the $b_n$ value calculated iteratively? Can it be calculated non-iteratively? What is the intuition behind using that method to calculate $b_2$?

Answer (score 2):

It is calculated the same way $b_1$ is calculated.

Nearly following your notation, say your multiple linear regression function is

$H(X_i) =  b_0 + b_1x_{1,i} + ...+ b_nx_{n, i}$

for data instance $X_i=x_{1,i},...,x_{n, i}$
and weights $b_0,...,b_n$.

And say your error function is $E(X,Y) = \sum_i(H(X_i)-Y_i)^2$

where $X$ is the collection of all data points $X_i, Y_i$.

From your error function $E$, for whatever weights you have (with a gradient based method), calculate the partial derivative
$\partial E /\partial b_i$ and use this to update all of your weights at once in each iteration of your optimization routine.

Answer (score -1):

put your b_1, ... ,b_n coefficients into a vector *b*

put all your x_{ij} into a matrix X

then all components of b are calculated at the same time with this equation

b = (H(X) - Xb)^T (H(x) - Xb)

But this calculation (estimation) is only consistent (search consistent estimator) when certain assumptions are present (read here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares).